# JVM option to output finalized objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, finalizer, yourkit

Is there a JVM option (`-XX` or otherwise) to log objects that are queued to be finalized? I'm debugging an application that has excessive finalizers which results in a huge amount of `java.lang.ref.Finalizer` instances (as seen in YourKit Java Profiler). It's difficult from looking at YourKit profiler which root object's `finalize` method is causing all the `Finalizer` instances.

Answer (score 0):

Do -verbose:gc, -XX:+PrintGCDetails and -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps give you enough info?

Comment: No, those switches do not contain the specific objects being collected or finalized.

Comment: In that case, I think you'll have to put some code on those finalizers.